# not being able to pass url parameters in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React.js web app , for some reasons I am not able to pass url parameters.

An example is being shown below:

Routes:

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Helloworld from './components/helloworld/helloworld.component';
import SecondView from './components/secondview/secondview.component';
import ThirdView from "./components/thirdview/thirdview.component";

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Route path='/thirdview/:number' component={ThirdView}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

);

export default AppRoutes;
```

Secondview Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class SecondView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("I am being called SecondView component...");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"boxDiv"}>
                <p>Second View</p>
                <Link to={{pathname: '/thirdview/7'}}> GO to third view with parameter value. </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(SecondView);
```

Thirdview comopnent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link,withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import FourthView from "../fourthview/fourthview.component";

class ThirdView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params);
        return (
            <div className={"boxDiv"}>
                <p>Third View</p>
                { console.log(this.props)}
                <h1>parameter passed: (#{this.props.params.number})</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(ThirdView);
```

What I want, is to be able to get /:number value on my thirdview component! Anyone knows how to achieve such thing in React.js? Are there other ways doing this?

What I get is empty object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
{this.props.match.params.number}
```

instead of

```
{this.props.params.number}
```

and you don't need `withRouter` on ThirdView and SecondView as are passed to `Route` already.

EDIT:

Since you want to render the same component for `/thirdview` and `/thirdview/7` use optional param matcher

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Helloworld}/>
    <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
    <Route path='/thirdview/:number?' component={ThirdView}/>
    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: i still get {} result!

Comment: when i log this.props.match i get {path: "/thirdview", url: "/thirdview", isExact: false, params: {…}}

Comment: @Mizlul see the edit and try again logging `this.props.match.params` in render.

Comment: made the changes and still getting {} when i try to log this.props.match.params

Comment: do you actually click the `Link` button to make redirect?

Comment: yes I am clicking also tried to log smth within componentDidMount and I can see the message but this.props.match.params within render() is still empty

Comment: can you make an example of this somewhere and show me how is it working?

Comment: wait!! its wokging :) forgot to remove <Route path='/thirdview' component={ThirdView}/> and leave only  <Route path='/thirdview/:number?' component={ThirdView}/>